# Al validar una etiqueta, no coincide el string

Tags: java, string

Tengo este código para escribir un `xml` pero al momento de validar la sentencia `if` no me lo toma en cuenta. ¿ Alguien sabe por qué ?

Como se valida una etiqueta `xml:`

```
for(int i=0; i<nodeList.size(); i++){
    if(nodeList.get(i).toString() == "</cfdi:Comprobante>"){
        System.out.println("hola");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar strings se utiliza la función **[equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))**, No deberías usar el operador `==`.

Por lo tanto esta debería debería realizar el trabajo correctamente:

```
  if(nodeList.get(i).toString().equals("</cfdi:Comprobante>")){
            System.out.println("hola");
  }
```